# Replicate object rotation inside rotated parent in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, quaternions, bounding-box

I built my 3D globe and placed it into a parent bounding box / pivot like this:

```
var globe = new THREE.Group();
if (earthmesh) {globe.add(earthmesh);};
if (linesmesh) {globe.add(linesmesh);};
if (cloudmesh) {globe.add(cloudmesh);};
if (atmosmesh) {globe.add(atmosmesh);};
pivot = new THREE.Group();
if (globe) {pivot.add(globe);};
if (pivot) {scene.add(pivot);};
```

so that when applying, say, a 23 degree rotation around the Z (far to near) axis on the parent:

```
pivot.rotation.set(THREE.Math.degToRad(0), THREE.Math.degToRad(0), THREE.Math.degToRad(23));
```

the globe would rotate around the Y (down to up) axis relative to its parent, in the animation function (in case you wonder, `v` is just an object holding the values for the `.loop` i.e. 360 degrees, `.rate` i.e. the rotation speed, as well as the `.roll`, `.spin` and `.tilt` variables corresponding to the X, Y and Z rotations of the globe, in degrees):

```
function animate()
{
  delta = clock.getDelta();
  resize();
  v.spin = (v.loop + v.spin + v.rate * delta) % v.loop;
  globe.rotation.set(THREE.Math.degToRad(v.roll), THREE.Math.degToRad(v.spin), THREE.Math.degToRad(v.tilt));
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

like the green arrow indicates below, instead of how the red arrow indicates if the globe had no rotated parent:

[image: Rotation Inside Pivot Parent]

This is very simple and it works well, if I do something like:

```
pivot.rotation.set(THREE.Math.degToRad(v.roll), THREE.Math.degToRad(0), THREE.Math.degToRad(v.tilt));
globe.rotation.set(THREE.Math.degToRad(0), THREE.Math.degToRad(v.spin), THREE.Math.degToRad(0));
```

in the animation function above and my on-demand / manual rotation system, without changing the camera position / direction as that is handled as desired by the ArcballControls library of Three.js, also visible above.

However, I would like to achieve this object rotation inside its parent by using other tools available in Three.js, like matrices, vectors, quaternions or other built-in functions, **without having to set a parent for the globe and distributing the rotations between the parent and the child**. The idea is to do the globe rotations normally like in the original animation function above, and apply some of those other tools (or even formulas) to alter the rotation and produce the desired effect. How can I do that?

In the interest of clarity, the benefit of such an approach over creating a parent for the globe would be that:

- I would be able to easily toggle between the "normal" (red arrow) and the "altered" (green arrow) rotation systems in an `if (...) {...}` condition without having to destroy, recreate or reset the parent - child construct
- I would be able to freely use the rotations around all the 3 axes for both the globe and the altering method, instead of applying some rotations on the parent and some on the child

Also, just in case I'll eventually settle on the parent - child approach above if the other methods are too complicated, how would I "reset" the rotation system to the "original" (i.e. red arrow) way in that case, without changing the object's visual orientation? I mean, resetting the `pivot` rotation to `(0, 0, 0)` is clear, but what would be the rotation applied to the globe child so that it stays the same even if its parent is now not rotated?

**Note:** For simplicity, a (0, 0, 0) position is assumed for both the parent and the child groups / objects and the parent rotation is illustrated on a single axis, but ideally, the alternative should allow different hypothetical positioning for the pivot and the object, while the globe altering rotation should be possible on all 3 axes.

**P.S.** Feel free to suggest improvements to how the question is formulated in order to make it clearer or more compact (sorry, I'm not an expert in technical terms, like world or local rotations or the like), but *try not to rush into marking it as a duplicate or closing it before you are absolutely sure about it*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty long, but I think what you're looking for is "rotation order". Rotations are typically applied to the x, then y, finally z axes.

You might want to put the earth's tilt (z) first, and daily spin (y) last, so you can change this with: `globe.rotation.order = "ZXY"`

[See here for official documentation on rotation order](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=object#api/en/math/Euler.order)

Comment: Ha! I never imagined changing the rotation order could be an answer to my problem - thanks, that's a very elegant way to do it indeed! I'll upvote this for now, and let one or two days pass before I'll mark a solution as the accepted answer, in case other answers are posted in the meantime. It does what I want and it's incredibly simple, but I'd be interested in seeing if a "rotation on top of another rotation" method is possible before making the final call. The question is this long only to provide all the possible information and to avoid complaints about not meeting the SO standards ;)

Comment: Haha! Yeah, it’s a fine line between too little info and too much info. Glad this helped.

Comment: For sure it helped, sorry for the length :) I just realized that the XZY order variant is the Z up axis system that's used in Blender and other tools, if the axes were called XYZ instead. I was thinking of switching the axes and let rotation order unchanged when toggling between systems in order to avoid moving the XYZ divs in the page to illustrate changing the rotation order, but then there is no good way of doing that without affecting everything else, not to mention I prefer the Three.js system anyway. Bar the design choices I'll have to make, your answer is gratefully marked as accepted.